# Term for the national systems that establish the rules

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am trying to find one term that describes the system that governs us, which includes both the economic system and political system. I want to find the right one term to talk about both democracy and capitalism, for example.

I have thought about :

- "governance model". But does it resonate too much like a corporate system?
- "polity". I found this term on the internet, but I worry this resonates too much with the actual instances of power, rather than the rule-system itself?
- "politico-economic system". It feels a little heavy?

Comment: While this question just about fits here (but you haven't followed all the guidelines in the tags), it is probably going to get better answers on [politics.se]. But I don't know enough about their tagging to just send it there.

Comment: "Politico-economic system" seems to be commonly used term if you want to emphasise both sides. Sorry if it's hard to type. But questions about political terminology are better asked on Politics SE.

Comment: _Culture_ is the usual term. It includes more than just politics and economics, but also is the real source of `The Rules`. Why are you wearing clothes? Not for political or economic reasons.

Comment: Are you referring to these things (capitalism and democracy) in the abstract, or specific instances like the US government and the Federal Reserve System? Can you show how you would use the word in a sentence?

Comment: Would the word _government_ fit? If not, could you explain why it wouldn't? Or possibly _form of government_?

Comment: **Why** do you want to find a **single** word that covers **both**? Political and economic system of a country are conceptually distinct, so it would seem that clarity would be promoted by using distinct terms for them.

Comment: Depending on your views or assumptions regarding who is in control, the terms oligarchy, aristocracy, and plutocracy might be in the word bank for consideration...or even technocracy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A term used to describe a country's political and economic system, together, is **political economy**.

> [Political economy](https://socialsci.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Political_Science_and_Civics/Introduction_to_Comparative_Government_and_Politics_(Bozonelos_et_al.)/08%3A_Political_Economy/8.01%3A_What_is_Political_Economy) is the relationship between the market and
> powerful actors, such as a country’s government.

Economics is how a nation chooses to allocate scarce resources for the production and distribution of goods and services. The political system includes the legal institutions that make up the government of a nation and its authority over its citizens, [see IMF: "Political Economy of Economic Policy"](https://www.imf.org/en/Publications/fandd/issues/2020/06/political-economy-of-economic-policy-jeff-frieden)

The types of economies are capitalist (free-market), command (e.g. communism), and hybrids. In a capitalist economy, individuals and businesses make their own economic decisions. In command economies, the state’s central government makes all of the country’s economic decisions.

Liberal capitalism is usually associated with democratic government. Command economies are usually associated with communist or authoritarian states. Hybrids such as [“bureaucratic authoritarian capitalism”](https://www.ineteconomics.org/perspectives/blog/the-crisis-of-democratic-capitalism) would be a communist bureaucracy operating a capitalist economy.

Keep in mind that these classifications are [not a taxonomy](https://www.amacad.org/publication/democratic-threat-capitalism) that can be consistently mixed and matched.

> There have been many historical instances of capitalism without
> liberal, representative democracy, but there are no known cases of
> liberal, representative democracy without capitalism.

Comment: "Political economy" describes the relationship, not the combination of the two.

Comment: Based on the definitions provided by the IMF, I believe that "political economy" does describe the combination of the two.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refer to it pejoratively, you could just call it **the system.** [The Free Dictionary defines this as:](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/system)

> The prevailing social order; the establishment. Used with "the": *You can't beat the system.*

Answer (score -2):

*Jurisdiction* may be a term you could use:

> **jurisdiction** [noun] [Merriam-Webster {amended}](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jurisdiction)
>
> •1 the power, right, or authority to interpret and apply the law
>
> ...
> •3 the limits or territory [domain] within which authority may
> be exercised / [over which the authority extends]

......

while [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/jurisdiction) adds the governmental system sense:

> **jurisdiction**: ...
>
> •5  a law court or system of law courts

Comment: Would we really call capitalism a jurisdiction?